# Target all a elements in a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried every combination/individual selector and cannot figure this one out.

I have a 'wrapper' page that has two primary divs with id's: 
toc-container
topic-container

The topic-container div has an html page loaded into it (that I cannot modify the source of), via the jquery .load function.

There are  tags in those loaded pages that have href elements that I need to loop through and change. Here is the html of the loaded page:

```
<div id="help-content">
<table class="relatedtopics aboveheading" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td width= "16">
                <p class="bodytext"><a href="overview.htm" target="_self"><img id="f126" src="126.gif" class="zzzembeddediconfiletemplate" alt="Home" height="16" width="17" vspace="0" hspace="0" align="bottom" border="0"></a></p></td>
            <td width= "16">
                <p class="bodytext"><a href="accessing_solutions.htm" target="_self"><img id="f125" src="125.gif" class="zzzembeddediconfiletemplate" alt="Previous Topic" height="16" width="17" vspace="0" hspace="0" align="bottom" border="0"></a></p></td>
            <td width= "16">
                <p class="bodytext"><a href="best_practice_browser.htm" target="_self"><img id="f124" src="124.gif" class="zzzembeddediconfiletemplate" alt="Next Topic" height="16" width="17" vspace="0" hspace="0" align="bottom" border="0"></a></p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <p class="bodytext">Contact your system administrator for instructions to change your password.</p>
    <p class="bodytext">Your administrator controls requirements for passwords, including the minimum character length, case requirements, and length of time until expiration. Contact your administrator for more information.</p>
    <p class="bodytext">Complete the following steps to change your password:</p>
    <ol class="numberlist"><li class="numberlist">On the Logon window, click the <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Change Password</span> link.</li><li class="numberlist">Enter your <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">User Name</span> and current <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Password</span>.</li><li class="numberlist">Enter your new password in the <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">New Password</span> and <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Confirm Password</span> fields.</li><li class="numberlist">Click <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Login</span>.</li></ol></div>
```

I have this function that is called after the page is loaded:

```
$('#help-content').find('a').each(function() {
    var initHref = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(initHref);
    var prefix = '?topicID=';
    var newHref = prefix+initHref;
    $(this).attr('href', newHref);
});
```

How can I change all href values in the page using jquery? I've tried targeting every selector possible : (

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/4210ehe2/ But you really don't need jQuery for this

Comment: it's working for me too .. i would guess your script is running before the `load` finishes, put it in the callback , try `$().load('url', function(){ ... your code here ... });`

Comment: @Taki OP says the script is running after the page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm just not getting it to work. Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/67ofk3gq/6/

Comment: Update - I figured out the problem. The 3rd-party html pages that I receive and load into the topic-container have this for a body tag: <body onload="if (isTOCLoaded()) {expand('141672');highlight('84599')"}>   removing the onload function fixes the problem. Frustrating : ( I will try to rewrite the body tag first with javascript and then rewrite the hrefs and hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following vanilla JavaScript statement to get all anchor tags on the page

```
document.querySelectorAll('a')
```

Hope this helps you to get an initial idea on how to extend it for your solution. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Your code works, but you were only logging the original
    `href` values. If you log again at the end of your code, you'd see the changes.**

2. A more simple selector would be just `$('#help-content a')` and then you wouldn't need the `.find()` method call.
3. The JQuery **[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** method is automatically passed arguments
   that make referencing the element being enumerated a bit more simple,
   so use that.
4. `_target=self` is only necessary if you are using the no
   longer supported `frameset` element in your code. By default, links
   open in the current window.
5. The `vspace` and `hspace` HTML attributes are deprecated.
6. All the other styling of your images (and your `td` elements, and really everything else) should really be done
   with CSS. And, because all your styling is identical for each of
   the    images, a single CSS rule can set them all up.
7. Although your code does work, your `prefix` and `newHref` variables
   aren't really necessary since you only use them once.

```js
// When the DOM is ready...
$(function(){
  $('#help-content a').each(function(idx, el) {
    var initHref = $(el).attr('href');
    $(el).attr('href', '?topicID=' + initHref);
    console.log("Original href: " + initHref, " - New href: " + $(el).attr('href'));     
  });
});
```

```css
/* Don't use HTML to style your page. That's what CSS is for.
   And, using CSS will remove the need for redundant HTML. */
#help-content img {
  height:16px;
  width:17px;
  text-align:bottom;
  border:none;
}

#help-content table.relatedtopics { border-collapse:collapse; border:none; border-spacing:0; }
#help-content table.relatedtopics tr { vertical-align:top; }
#help-content table.relatedtopics td { padding:0; width:16px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="help-content">
  <table class="relatedtopics aboveheading">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="bodytext">
          <a href="overview.htm">
            <img id="f126" src="126.gif" class="zzzembeddediconfiletemplate" alt="Home">
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="bodytext">
          <a href="accessing_solutions.htm">
            <img id="f125" src="125.gif" class="zzzembeddediconfiletemplate" alt="Previous Topic">
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="bodytext">
          <a href="best_practice_browser.htm">
            <img id="f124" src="124.gif" class="zzzembeddediconfiletemplate" alt="Next Topic">
          </a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p class="bodytext">Contact your system administrator for instructions to change your password.</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Your administrator controls requirements for passwords, including the minimum character length, case requirements, and length of time until expiration. Contact your administrator for more information.</p>
  <p class="bodytext">Complete the following steps to change your password:</p>
  
  <ol class="numberlist">
    <li class="numberlist">On the Logon window, click the 
      <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Change Password</span> link.
    </li>
    <li class="numberlist">Enter your <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">User Name</span> and current <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Password</span>.
    </li>
    <li class="numberlist">Enter your new password in the <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">New Password</span> and <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Confirm Password</span> fields.
    </li>
    <li class="numberlist">Click <span class="procedureinterfaceelement">Login</span>.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but the html that is loaded into the topic-container is not mine - it is 3rd-party content, which is why I'm using the .load() method to bring it in. I don't control that html source, so I'm trying to at least change the incorrectly pathed 'href' attributes in them.

Comment: @user172586 My solution does exactly what you are asking for. It doesn't care where the content comes from. As long as the resulting content is in a container with an `id` of `help-content`. The code will work.

Comment: Hi Scott - thank you for your help, I do appreciate it very much. Unfortunately, it's not working for me. It's changing only one link's href. I must be doing something wrong, so I will keep working on it.

Comment: @user172586 Yes, you must have something specific to how you are implementing this causing a problem. As you can see, this solution does work on all the `a` elements located within the `help-content` container.